# C++ std::string syntax "new (&y) std::string(x);"

Tags: c++, string, constructor

How to understand the following `std::string` init syntax?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main ()
{
    std::string y;
    std::string x = "x str";
    new (&y) std::string(x);
    std::cout << y << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
x str
```

Can we split the statement into 2 steps?

1.

```
string* temp = new std::string(x);
```

2.

```
(&y) = temp
```

So the original statement is just a shortcut for step 1 + 2.

Reference:

1.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string

2.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string

Comment: There's nothing special here except the use of [placement new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new), which isn't commonly used in code.

Answer (score 6):

This is called "placement new". The basic idea is that you supply an address, and it invokes the constructor for that type to create an object at that address.

In a typical case, you'd give it an address that's "raw" memory though, not the address of an existing object. In fact, I'm not sure the code above really has defined behavior (though I'd have to look at the standard carefully to be sure whether it does or not).

It's most often used for things like collection classes, which allocate raw memory, the when you do something like `insert` or `push_back`, it constructs an object in that memory. The standard collections objects go through an allocator object to handle the construction, but in the end, it'll (at least usually) end up as placement new doing the real work.

The parameters you pass to `new` will be passed through to the constructor for the object being created. So in your case, it'll copy `x` into a new string at `y`'s address (i.e., it'll replace `y` with a copy of `x`).

Comment: What is the input and return value of the `new` function? For example `void* operator new(std::size_t, void*)`? The syntax is uncommon for me to understand.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the above example will cause it to fail to run the destructor of any data in the default constructed string, which is normally nullptr. Not great, but likely not catastrophic.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh UB is still UB, which the code in the question invokes.

Comment: @Fureeish But it doesn't invoke UB, does it? Calling placement new on an object that was already initialized, although prone to resource leaks, as long as it is the same object as before, it well-defined, correct?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27552466/c-is-constructing-object-twice-using-placement-new-undefined-behaviour

Comment: It's bad code, don't get me wrong. I just don't believe it invokes UB.

Comment: @Fureeish I sincerely doubt this is UB, unless you can prove that the program relies on side effects running from the destructor of `std::string` (which `basic_string` shouldn't be allowed to do):
https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/pull/2342#issuecomment-428428936

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh you are correct here, my apologies.

Comment: Reusing the storage of an object with a non-trivial destructor results in undefined behavior only if the application "depends on the side effects of the destructor".  It's not really defined what that means though AFAIK.