# C++ custom allocator size argument as template parameter throws compiler error

Tags: c++

The following code gives me expected result when I use custom allocator for my container (keeping the size sz as global variable)

```
#include <cstddef> /* size_t */
#include <new> /* Only for bad_alloc */
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
std::size_t constexpr sz = 4;
template <typename T> class StaticAllocator {
protected:
    static T buf[sz];
public:
    typedef T value_type;
    T* allocate(std::size_t const n) {
        if (n > sz) throw std::bad_alloc();
        return buf;
    }
    void deallocate(T*, std::size_t) {}
};
template<typename T> T StaticAllocator<T>::buf[sz];
int main(void) {
    std::vector<char, StaticAllocator<char> > v;
    v.push_back('a');
    v.push_back('b');
    for (auto const& i : v) cout << i << endl;
}
```

where as this version of code gives me compiler error when I try to use the size as template parameter for the class

```
#include <cstddef> /* size_t */
#include <new> /* bad_alloc */
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
template<typename T, std::size_t sz> class StaticAllocator {
protected:
    static T buf[sz];
public:
    typedef T value_type;
    T* allocate(std::size_t const n) {
        if (n > sz) throw std::bad_alloc();
        return buf;
    }
    void deallocate(T*, std::size_t) {}
};
template<typename T, std::size_t sz> T StaticAllocator<T, sz>::buf[sz];
int main(void) {
    std::vector<char, StaticAllocator<char, 4> > v;
    v.push_back('a');
    v.push_back('b');
    for (auto const& i : v) cout << i << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get an allocator for some type `U` from an allocator for type `T`, member alias template [`std::allocator_traits::rebind_alloc<U>`](http://eel.is/c++draft/allocator.traits#types-11) is used [allocator.traits.types]:

> `Alloc::rebind<T>::other` if `Alloc::rebind<T>::other` is valid and
>   denotes a type; otherwise, `Alloc<T, Args>` if `Alloc` is a class template instantiation of the form `Alloc<U, Args>`, where `Args` is zero or more type arguments; otherwise, the instantiation of `rebind_alloc` is ill-formed.

Note that `Args` are **type** template parameters. In your allocators there is no `rebind`. In the first case `Alloc<U>` is used, `Args` is empty. But in the second case, the second template parameter is a **non-type** one, it cannot be matched by `Args`.

You need to manually add `rebind` member struct:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t sz>
class StaticAllocator {
    // ...

    template<class U>
    struct rebind {
        using other = StaticAllocator<U, sz>;
    };
};
```

Also note that your allocator is broken for some general type `S`. First, `buf` will be initialized by default constructing `sz` objects `S`. Then, it will be overwritten by newly constructing `S`s at the same location before destructing the existing ones. The similar thing happens upon reallocation. This can lead to undefined behaviour. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41385355/is-it-ok-not-to-call-the-destructor-on-placement-new-allocated-objects) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27552466/c-is-constructing-object-twice-using-placement-new-undefined-behaviour) questions for some details.

---

The following solution was proposed in the now-deleted answer: inherit from `std::allocator<T>`:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t sz> class StaticAllocator : 
    public std::allocator<T> {
// ...
};
```

The code compiles and runs, but... `StaticAllocator::allocate` and `StaticAllocator::deallocate` are **not** called (at least in libstdc++). The reason is that internally `std::vector` always [uses `rebind`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_vector.h#L83) to get the allocator type:

```
using Tp_alloc_type = 
    typename gnu_cxx::alloc_traits<Alloc>::template rebind<Tp>::other;
```

`rebind` is inherited from `std::allocator<T>` and it returns `std::allocator` instead of `StaticAllocator`. That's why you still have to provide your own `rebind` in `StaticAllocator`.

Comment: As per your suggestion, I modified my class definition and it worked like a charm. Thank you. `template<typename T, std::size_t sz> class StaticAllocator {
protected:
    static T buf[sz];
public:
    typedef T value_type;
    template<typename U> struct rebind { typedef StaticAllocator<U, sz> other; };
    T* allocate(std::size_t const n) {
        if (n > sz) throw std::bad_alloc();
        return buf;
    }
    void deallocate(T *, std::size_t) {}
};`